# How to make a std::shared_ptr from a non-pointer object?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

As output from one function, I get an object of type `Foo`.  As an argument to another class, I need to pass an object of type `std::shared_ptr<Foo>`.  How can I make the shared pointer from the original object?

Comment: Can you change the function returning Foo or the function taking shared_ptr<Foo>, or are they both from some third-party library or something? (And, if so, maybe if you tell us which one, we can skim the docs and figure out what the intent is.)

Comment: And this is why taking `shared_ptr` arguments is suboptimal and should be avoided.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is really quite simple:

```
auto val = std::make_shared<Foo>(FuncThatReturnsFoo(...));
```

Basically, just heap allocate a new `Foo`, copying/moving the result into it.

Comment: shouldn't that be `std::make_shared<Foo>(FuncThatReturnsFoo(...))`?

Comment: I think the template parameter to make_shared needs to be explicit. `make_shared<Foo>(FuncThatReturnsFoo(...))`.

Comment: @bames53: I was going to fix it, but Jonathan got there first.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't do that if I were you. Mainly because `std::shared_ptr` manages memory, whereas if you get an object as a return type, the memory is managed automatically (usually, and most likely).

You'll either have to create a new object in dynamic storage

```
Foo getObject();
//...
std::shared_ptr<Foo> ptr(new Foo(getObject())); //construct new object in dynamic memory
                                                //using the copy constructor
```

or change the function to return a pointer to an object whose memory you manage.

```
Foo getObject(); 
//becomes
Foo* getObject();
//or, even better
std::shared_ptr<Foo> getObject();
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this:

1. Create a new copy on the heap and make a shared_ptr from that.
2. Make a shared_ptr from it with a null deleter.

The first can be done by writing

```
auto newPtr = std::make_shared<Foo>( foo );
```

This works, if the class `Foo` is copy-constructable. The second thing can be accomplished by

```
auto newPtr = std::shared_ptr<Foot>( &foo, [](void*){} );
```

Here you don't create a new copy of the object. However, this is only safe, if you can guarantee that the pointer is not accessed, after `foo` goes out of scope. Otherwise, you will access a destroyed object and you program is likely to do random stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you want to prevent heap-allocation otherwise just heap-allocate a copy of the returned object and go ahead.

You need to prevent that the deleter actually deletes something and need the stack to take care of this:

```
// given the signatures
Foo f();
void other(std::shared_ptr<Foo> x);

Foo my_f = f();
std::shared_ptr<Foo> my_fptr{&my_f, [](Foo*) {}};
other(my_fptr);
```

That is a real code smell, though. Why would a function accept a
`shared_ptr` if not to extend life-time?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
std::shared_ptr<Foo> ptr(new Foo(f());
```

Semantically, it's making a copy of the return value, but the copy constructor should be elided.